# Laravel cache driver

Tags: php, laravel, caching, rate

I use Laravel version 9 and use API requests in my routes. I wanted to configure RateLimiter in the RouteServiceProvider file, but it doesn't work when I use the .env setting **CACHE_DRIVER=array**.

But if I put **CACHE_DRIVER=file**, then RateLimiter works fine.
But then after authorization I see the error "This cache store does not support tagging."
If I reload the page, the error disappears.

Tell me pls what the problem is, so that both **RateLimiter and CACHE_DRIVER=file** work without this error when authorizing the user?

Thanks!

Comment: The `array` cache driver should only be used in testing. The cache is cleared on every request (making it a very bad cache). The `file` cache driver does not support tagging and is also a pretty slow cache. If you have a serious application consider installing and using a proper in memory cache like redis or memcache https://github.com/microweber-packages/laravel-tagged-file-cache might help if you must use the file cache and tagging as well

Comment: Additionally you can add an specific cache driver for limiter, which by default use default cache configured. In your cache config you can add something like 'limiter' => 'redis', https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting#cache-configuration

Answer (score 4):

The array cache driver is an in-memory cache and is only live for the request it is used. Once the request is completed then that cache is effectively gone. As mentioned in a comment above it is generally used for the test environment.

You're best to use another cache driver for development - preferably the same as what you use in production. But failing that the file driver is the easiest fallback.